# Ecryptfs: lost passphrase

Tags: password, data-recovery, ecryptfs, password-recovery

When I mounted some dir by

```
mount -t ecryptfs private data
```

I entered wrong password. I wrote data in this dir and now I can't mount it. I have no valid password and passphrase (know only the same), but have SIG in `/root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt`.

How I can recover my directory or, at least, **brute it**: type many-many passwords like entered when mounting this dir and compare generated sig with existing?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to try a bunch of passprhases, and compare them with your known signature, you can use the [ecryptfs-add-passphrase](http://manpg.es/ecryptfs-add-passphrase) command.  That will take whatever passphrase you enter, and add it to the kernel's keyring and return the signature.

You can do that a bunch of times (perhaps in a script), until you get the right signature.

You may want to clear out all of those added passphrase (or perhaps clear your kernel keyring between each try).  For that, you'll want to use [keyctl](http://manpg.es/keyctl) clear @u.

*Full disclosure: I am one of the authors and maintainers of [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org).*